# monitoring gearman in nagios

Tags: linux, nagios, gearman

I am trying to monitor gearman by nagios for that I am using script `check_gearman.sh`.

Localhost is where gearman server running.

When I run

```
./check_gearman.sh -H localhost -p 4730 -t 1000
```

It results in:

> CRITICAL: gearman: gearman_client_run_tasks : gearman_wait(GEARMAN_TIMEOUT) timeout reached, 1 servers were poll(), no servers were available, pipe:false -> libgearman/universal.cc:331: pid(613)

Can some one please help me out in this.

below is script

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# gearman check for nagios
# written by Georg Thoma (georg@thoma.cn)
# Last modified: 07-04-2014
#
# Description:
#
#
#

PROGNAME=`/usr/bin/basename $0`
PROGPATH=`echo $0 | sed -e 's,[\\/][^\\/][^\\/]*$,,'`
REVISION="0.04"
export TIMEFORMAT="%R"

. $PROGPATH/utils.sh

# Defaults
hostname=localhost
port=4730
timeout=50

# search for gearmanstuff
GEARMAN_BIN=`which gearman 2>&1 | grep -v "no gearman in"`
if [ "x$GEARMAN_BIN" == "x" ] ; then # result of check is empty
   echo "gearman executable not found in path"
   exit $STATE_UNKNOWN
fi
GEARADMIN_BIN=`which gearadmin 2>&1 | grep -v "no gearadmin in"`
if [ "x$GEARADMIN_BIN" == "x" ] ; then # result of check is empty
   echo "gearadmin executable not found in path"
   exit $STATE_UNKNOWN
fi


print_usage() {
    echo "Usage: $PROGNAME [-H hostname -p port -t timeout]"
    echo "Usage: $PROGNAME --help"
    echo "Usage: $PROGNAME --version"
}

print_help() {
    print_revision $PROGNAME $REVISION
    echo ""
    print_usage
    echo ""
    echo "gearman check plugin for nagios"
    echo ""
    support
}

# Make sure the correct number of command line
# arguments have been supplied

if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
    print_usage
    exit $STATE_UNKNOWN
fi

# Grab the command line arguments

exitstatus=$STATE_WARNING #default
while test -n "$1"; do
    case "$1" in
        --help)
            print_help
            exit $STATE_OK
            ;;
        -h)
            print_help
            exit $STATE_OK
            ;;
        --version)
            print_revision $PROGNAME $REVISION
            exit $STATE_OK
            ;;
        -V)
            print_revision $PROGNAME $REVISION
            exit $STATE_OK
            ;;
        -H)
            hostname=$2
            shift
            ;;
        --hostname)
            hostname=$2
            shift
            ;;
        -t)
            timeout=$2
            shift
            ;;
        --timeout)
            timeout=$2
            shift
            ;;
        -p)
            port=$2
            shift
            ;;
        --port)
            port=$2
            shift
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Unknown argument: $1"
            print_usage
            exit $STATE_UNKNOWN
            ;;
    esac
    shift
done

# check if server is running and replys to version query
VERSION_RESULT=`$GEARADMIN_BIN -h $hostname -p $port --server-version 2>&1 `
if [ "x$VERSION_RESULT" == "x" ] ; then # result of check is empty
      echo "CRITICAL: Server is not running / responding"
      exitstatus=$STATE_CRITICAL
      exit $exitstatus
fi

# drop funtion echo to remove functions without workers
DROP_RESULT=`$GEARADMIN_BIN -h $hostname -p $port --drop-function echo_for_nagios 2>&1 `

# check for worker echo_for_nagios and start a new one if needed
CHECKWORKER_RESULT=`$GEARADMIN_BIN -h $hostname -p $port --status | grep echo_for_nagios`
if [ "x$CHECKWORKER_RESULT" == "x" ] ; then # result of check is empty
   nohup $GEARMAN_BIN -h $hostname -p $port -w -f echo_for_nagios -- echo echo >/dev/null 2>&1 &
fi

# check the time to get the status from gearmanserver
CHECKWORKER_TIME=$( { time $GEARADMIN_BIN -h $hostname --status ; } 2>&1 |tail -1 )

# check if worker returns "echo"
CHECK_RESULT=`cat /dev/null | $GEARMAN_BIN -h $hostname -p $port -t $timeout -f echo_for_nagios 2>&1`

# validate result and set message and exitstatus
if [ "$CHECK_RESULT" = "echo" ] ; then # we got echo back
      echo "OK: got an echo back from gearman server version: $VERSION_RESULT, responded in $CHECKWORKER_TIME sec|time=$CHECKWORKER_TIME;;;"
      exitstatus=$STATE_OK
   else  # timeout reached, no echo
      echo "CRITICAL: $CHECK_RESULT"
      exitstatus=$STATE_CRITICAL
fi
exit $exitstatus
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you download the `mod_gearman` package, this contains a much better and more featured `check_gearman` plugin for Nagios.

With your current plugin, the error message shows that the check script cannot connect to the gearman daemon.

You should verify that port 4370 is listening on localhost, and that there is no local firewall blocking connections.  It is likely that you have installed your gearmand on a different port, or have it only listening on the network interface, not on localhost.  Or maybe it is not runing at all, or is on a different server from the one running the check...